# How can I debug/get output from a microcontroller using cc-debugger?

Tags: microcontroller, serial, uart, debugging

I am working with [TI's CC2540](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2540&DCMP=LowPowerRFICs+Other&HQS=Other+OT+cc2540) SoC using [CC2540dk-mini](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2540dk-mini). My software stack is:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- [sdcc](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) Compiler
- [cc-tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cctool/) to flash programs onto board using cc-debugger

I can compile, build and flash firmwares perfectly (until now) using these tools. But I do not know how to debug (toggle breakpoints, see sfr values, etc.) or even to "print" from CC2540.

Chapter 3 from [CC2540 user guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru191d/swru191d.pdf) talks about the debug interface, and reading it I notice that flash programming is done using this interface. So... aparently to debug the firmware I would have to extend cc-tool. It sounds right?

About printing: reading the [sdcc user guide](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/doc/sdccman.pdf) (section 3.17.2.1) I realize that I have to provide `putchar()` function, which makes sense. But what low level protocol should I use? USART? Or something else? (debug interface?) How the CC2540 can talk with cc-debugger? How cc-debugger can talk with Ubuntu?

This all seems a little vague, but it is because I have no experience in this "field" (I always used Arduino and I never had to go in this "low level" before).

Comment: With Arduino, you are adapting a runtime communication scheme (serial over USB) to briefly talk to a bootloader on the chip.  In contrast, the CC debugger talks to dedicated logic in the chip, and isn't really intended for runtime communication from a user program.  There may be a specific secondary capability built into it for that.  Or if not, you may be able to create a communication channel by having the debugger monitor mailbox variables for information from the program, and then set a flag to let the program know the message has been collected and can be overwritten by a new one.

Comment: Why not use Code composer studio?? You get a free license with you dev kit (see here http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Licensing_-_CCS), they have a version that runs in linux. Using the full IDE will take away the complexity of setting up your debug environment. As to putchar() the communication interface is your choice, I doubt that you can use the debbuger interface but pretty much take your pick from the available communication interfaces in you micro.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using code composer and you should(Keil uvision is a other good option). When you must select in the Flash button's arrow the "debug" option(little insect icon).

[image]

Than when you are going to Flash your MCU a interface will open showing the register and where you can track variable values.

Regards, MathieuL.